# Calculation of values based on the color of cells in Excel VBA

Tags: colors, formula, average, calculation

The code shows a simple average calculation based on the values in the defined cells. Those cells are highlighted in three colors. The aim is to take the values into the calcuation which cell color is e.g. green. I know the "if" command is needed, I just dont know where excatly to put it in:

[image]

```
 Dim wb As Workbook, wq As Object
 Dim ws As Worksheet, datdatum
 Dim cell As Range, cell2 As Range, col As Long


 ws.Range("H104:U104").Formula = "= Average(H34,H39,H68,H71,H83)"
```

Comment: So you would need to examine every cell in every column from H:U independently. Probably better to use a UDF. Are the 'colors' manually set or conditional formatted?

Comment: The colors are pre-conditionally set. What does UDF stand for? Thank you for your effort.

Comment: **Are the 'colors' manually set or conditional formatted?**

Comment: They are conditional formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that entire rows are not green and that each column needs to be looked at independently.

Loop through each column from H to U. Loop through each cell in each column. Build a union of the cells that are green and average the union. Move on to the next column.

There is no point in building a formula for each column since any change would require rerunning the sub procedure. These will work on both manually set and conditional formatted cell colors.

.DisplayFormat does not work within a User Defined Function.

```
dim c as long, r as long, rng as range

with worksheets("sheet1")

    for c =8 to 21
        for r=2 to 103
            if .cells(r, c).displayformat.interior.color = vbgreen then
                if rng is nothing then
                    set rng = .cells(r, c)
                else
                    set rng = union(rng, .cells(r, c))
                end if
            end if
        next r

        if not rng is nothing then _
            .cells(104, c) = application.average(rng)
        'alternate
        'if not rng is nothing then _
            '.cells(104, c).formula = "=average(" & rng.address(0,0) & ")"
    next c

end with
```

Alternate,

```
dim c as long

with worksheets("sheet1")
    if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode = false

    for c =8 to 21
        with .range(.cells(1, c), .cells(103, c))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=vbgreen, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            .cells(104, c) = application.subtotal(101, .cells)
            .AutoFilter
        end with
    next c

end with
```

Comment: I have just uploaded an image for clarity. Thank you for your code, I will tried it out tomorrow. Much appreciated

Comment: You are going to have to determine exactly what shade of green you are using in the CFR. Could be vbGreen, could be RGB(146, 208 , 80), could be other.

Comment: I have used "vbGreen". Thx

Comment: Hi Jeeped, the code worked perfectly. However, i would like to have the formula included in the cell not only the calcualted value.  I tried this: .Cells(104, c).Formula = "= Average(rng)", but didnt work much

Comment: You cannot use a vba range in a worksheet formula directly. You *can* however, use its address.

Comment: I did and it works beautifully, however if you use the alternative with the formula init, there is the code " end if" missing at the end after      '.cells(104, c).formula = "=average(" & rng.address(0,0) & ")"
    next c

Comment: One more Thing, I noticed the code accumulates all the values in green cells for the calculation. I just want an average calculation of the green mark values in each row seperately not accumulated